# How to have one line string when passing in values using envsubst command?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, envsubst

When using envsubst to replace values in a file, it creates a newline when it appends to a string. How do I prevent it from inserting a newline when saving it to a new file?

Environment Variable:
`foo=bar`

File:
`$foo\\text\\word,$foo\\text2\\word2,$foo\\text3\\word3`

Command:
`envsubst < test.properties > temp.properties`

Undesired output:

```
bar
\\text\\word,bar
\\text2\\word2,bar
\\text3\\word3
```

Desired output:
`bar\\text\\word,bar\\text2\\word2,bar\\text3\\word3`

Comment: I get the _Desired_, can't reproduce the _Undesired output_.

Comment: are you sure foo doesn't contain a newline in its value?

Comment: @stark Yes, i've doubled check if there was and did not see any

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar issue with a string in file where I need to replace something like this:

```
my_string_$VAR_that_continues
```

I managed to solve this protecting the variable name inside the string like this:

```
my_string_${VAR}_that_continues
```

And then use the envsubst command normally.
Hope it still helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pipe to `tr` to remove the newlines

```
$ echo "foo\nbar" | tr -d '\n'
foobar
```